# Selenium Webdriver Mobile with Python - AndroidWebdriver4Python installation question

Tags: selenium, webdriver, python, android

[I found this Android webdriver API on github](https://github.com/truebit/AndroidWebDriver4Python).

I already have the Selenium Python client and have written many plain web-based test scripts with it. I have tried asking the git owner, but he has not responded.

Here are the instructions:

1. download AndroidWebDriver4Python using command:

   `$ git clone git://github.com/truebit/AndroidWebDriver4Python.git`
2. Download and extract Selenium Python client
3. Copy the entire py folder under AndroidWebDriver4Python to merge the same one in root directory of AndroidDriver for Python
4. Back to the root directory of Selenium Python Client, to install this modified version using command:

   `$ python setup.py install`

What does number 3 mean? It sounds like he's saying to copy the py folder into itself. Shouldn't it go into the Lib folder of your Python27 folder?

Also, I don't understand step 4. Won't this reinstall your Selenium Python client?

Answer (score 4):

I am the author.

Actually this is a patch-like binding. 
You should know what I said in step 2. You need to download the source code of [official Python bindings for Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) and then copy my patch to the source files and install the patch source code, as mentioned in step 3 and 4.

Comment: Huh? Could you explain Step 3 another way?     'So what you need to do is to download the source code of AndroidWebDriver and then execute step 3 and 4.' just sounds like a repeat of your instructions. I don't understand step 3 or step 4. I have already downloaded the AndroidWebDriver and have used Webdriver with Python for plain web scripts already.

Comment: @StacyM Sorry, I made typo. I updated the answer.

Comment: What does "copy my patch to the source files" mean?

Comment: It means copy the dir of https://github.com/truebit/AndroidWebDriver4Python/tree/master/py to official source of selenium bindings

Comment: What does "official source of selenium bindings" mean? What folder specifically and what directory?

Comment: eh... maybe you should ask some guys around who know python a bit more...

Comment: Do you mean the ..\Python27\Lib\site-packages folder, where Selenium was installed? I also have things like pip, setuptools, easy_install and virtualenv here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @StacyM he is talking about the path `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver` you can place the `android` file there. Also in your `__init__.py` file you can add the line `from android.webdriver import WebDriver as Android` if what I have read is correct. Maybe @Sean can confirm this?

EDIT: I did get this working by removing my old Selenium, unpacking the newest selenium in the site-packages, then taking the android package and adding the way I suggested above. After all of this went to command line @ `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium` (this directory might include numbers after selenium) and ran the script `python setup.py install`. Let me know if this works for you.